# matplotlib bar chart example not matching website

Tags: python, matplotlib

i am running the below code in python 2, taken directly from this site:

http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/barchart_demo.html

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib inline

N = 5
men_means = (20, 35, 30, 35, 27)
men_std = (2, 3, 4, 1, 2)

ind = np.arange(N)  # the x locations for the groups
width = 0.35       # the width of the bars

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
rects1 = ax.bar(ind, men_means, width, color='r', yerr=men_std)

women_means = (25, 32, 34, 20, 25)
women_std = (3, 5, 2, 3, 3)
rects2 = ax.bar(ind + width, women_means, width, color='y', yerr=women_std)

# add some text for labels, title and axes ticks
ax.set_ylabel('Scores')
ax.set_title('Scores by group and gender')
ax.set_xticks(ind + width / 2)
ax.set_xticklabels(('G1', 'G2', 'G3', 'G4', 'G5'))

ax.legend((rects1[0], rects2[0]), ('Men', 'Women'))


def autolabel(rects):
    """
    Attach a text label above each bar displaying its height
    """
    for rect in rects:
        height = rect.get_height()
        ax.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width()/2., 1.05*height,
                '%d' % int(height),
                ha='center', va='bottom')

autolabel(rects1)
autolabel(rects2)

plt.show()
```

what is strange is that when this displays the first bar corresponding to "G1" displays touching the edge of the y-axis, and not how it shows on the website.

i am having this same issue with other bar charts im creating so trying to understand how i can space the bars out - basically leaving a margin on either side.

[image: MY OUTPUT]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example you link to is for matplotlib version 2.0. However you are running 1.5 or below. So you need to refer to the example of the previous versions: [barchart example for 1.5](http://matplotlib.org/1.5.3/examples/api/barchart_demo.html).
Alternatively, you can update matplotlib to version 2.0.

In order to add space at the edges, you can use

```
plt.margins(x=0.05)  or  ax.margins(x=0.05)
```

with any number as a fraction of axis length you like.
Alternatively you can set the limits of the axes,like

```
plt.xlim((0,N))  or  ax.set_xlim((0,N))
```

where N is the number of bars.